# GitHub Convert Clone to Fork (after the fact)

Tags: git, github

First, as you read this, you may be asking yourself, "Why?"  The reason is due to a political nature (got to love working within large enterprises :) ).

**Situation:**

There is a repo on github.  Let's say `/github.com/someorg/demorepo`.
I've created my own repo in my own org (i.e. `/github.com/myorg/demorepo`).

Currently, these two repos are not "attached".

Is there a way that I can tell GitHub that `/myorg/demorepo` is a fork of `/someorg/demorepo` so that I can do PRs? (I can't check-in directly to `/someorg/demorepo`.)

Thanks!

Comment: Your repo (on your computer, I mean) is allowed to have two remotes. Typically the thing you've forked from is named `upstream`, while the thing you've got in your own GitHub account is called `origin` — though both those names are arbitrary and merely conventional. So, with some care, you can update yourself from the `upstream` and push the changes to `origin`. You cannot directly manipulate the remotes of the github repo now that you've created it independently; you would have needed to start by forking _on GitHub_ to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s what I would do:

1. Fork the repo properly on GitHub
2. On any local clones of the original you have, do `git remote set-url origin <fork-url>` (and again with `--push`)
3. `git push` to update the fork, as usual

If you want to keep a reference to the « upstream » repo, the canonical way is `git remote add upstream <upstream-url>`

Comment: I can't "fork the repo" on GitHub as the fork needs to exist under my company's GitHub org and, while I can create net new repos in the org, I cannot fork to a new repo in the org.

Comment: By “on GitHub” I think it’s reasonable to assume I meant “on whichever GitHub has the repo”—if you can create new repos, you should be perfectly capable of forking one. That usually requires even less privileges? Ultimately, I cannot solve that issue for you